# Как сделать активный клик на javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть див, хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на него появлялась полоска (hr), но выполнить это нужно так, чтобы полоска появлялась только на время нажатия (типа псевдокласса :active в CSS)

Т.е. пока проходит нажатие полоска должна висеть, как нажатие на кнопку прекратилось - полоска исчезает. Как это сделать на java script/jquery?

`<div id="first">`

```
#first {width: 100%; height: 15%;}
```

Comment: Слушать событие `mousedown` - показать `hr`, событие `mouseup` - убрать\спрятать элемент.

Comment: события mouseenter mouseleave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в кратце: на событие `onmousedown` - показываем `hr`, на событие `onmouseup` убираем. Лучше даже сделать это с помощью css добавляя диву просто класс

```js
first.onmousedown = function () {
  this.classList.add('active');
}

first.onmouseup = function () {
  this.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
hr {
  display: none;
}

#first.active + hr {
  display: block;
}

#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id='first'></div>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вашу (странную) затею, то так:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '.new-block', function() {
  $(this).find('hr').css('opacity', 1);
});
$(document).on('mouseup', '.new-block', function() {
  $(this).find('hr').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
.new-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

hr {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="new-block">
  Первый<hr/>
</div>

<div class="new-block">
  Второй<hr/>
</div>

<div class="new-block">
  Трейтий<hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без скриптов, добавив атрибут `tabindex`, тогда будет работать псевдокласс `:active`

```css
hr {
  display: none;
}

#first:active + hr {
  display: block;
}

#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='first' tabindex></div>
<hr>
```